# Flip bits in array using python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, bit-manipulation, bit

You are given an integer array with `N` elements: `d[0], d[1], ... d[N - 1]`. 
You can perform AT MOST one move on the array: choose any two integers `[L, R]`, and flip all the elements between (and including) the `L`-th and `R`-th bits. `L` and `R` represent the left-most and right-most index of the bits marking the boundaries of the segment which you have decided to flip.

What is the maximum number of `1`-bits (indicated by `S`) which you can obtain in the final bit-string?

'Flipping' a bit means, that a `0` is transformed to a `1` and a `1` is transformed to a `0` (`0->1`,`1->0`).

Input Format: An integer `N`, next line contains the `N` bits, separated by spaces: `d[0] d[1] ... d[N - 1]`

Output: `S`

Constraints:

```
1 <= N <= 100000,
d[i] can only be 0 or 1 ,
0 <= L <= R < n ,
```

Sample Input:

```
8

1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

Sample Output:  `6`

Explanation:

We can get a maximum of 6 ones in the given binary array by performing either of the following operations:

```
Flip [1, 5] ==> 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: I'm confused by your "Solution" - how can you start with `flip = [1, 5]` when it's not given as input? It seems the problem is asking you to find that as well, not start with it. This may also explain why it only took you 2 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Karin for the solution. And I should have been clear. this interview question was old and was already answered in C. Was looking for a python solution.

Comment: @Karin if you could check out my solution, I'd appreciate your input. I know it's late over there in Pittsburgh...

Comment: Your title and post mention arrays and you use the `list` tag. So which one do you use?

Answer (score 3):

#### Cleaned up and made Pythonic

```
arr1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
arr2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
arr3 = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]


def maximum_ones(arr):
    """
    Returns max possible number of ones after flipping a span of bit array
    """  

    total_one = 0
    net = 0
    maximum = 0
    for bit in arr:
        if bit:
            total_one += 1
            net -= 1
        else:
            net += 1
        maximum = max(maximum, net)
        if net < 0:
            net = 0
    return total_one + maximum

print(maximum_ones(arr1))
print(maximum_ones(arr2))
print(maximum_ones(arr3))
```

Output:

```
6
14
11
```

#### If we want the L and R indices

Not so sure about this one. It can probably be made cleaner.

```
arr1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
arr2_0 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
arr2_1 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
arr2_2 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
arr3 = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]


def maximum_ones(arr):
    """
    Returns max possible number of ones after flipping a span of bit array
    and the (L,R) indices (inclusive) of such a flip
    """ 
    total_one = 0
    net = 0
    maximum = 0
    L = R = 0
    started_flipping = False
    for i, bit in enumerate(arr):
        if bit:
            total_one += 1
            net -= 1
        else:
            net += 1
            if not started_flipping:
                started_flipping = True
                L = i
        if net > maximum:
            maximum = net
            R = i
        if net < 0:
            net = 0
            if i < R:
                L = i
    return (total_one + maximum, (L,R))

print(maximum_ones(arr1))
print(maximum_ones(arr2_0))
print(maximum_ones(arr2_1))
print(maximum_ones(arr2_2))
print(maximum_ones(arr3))
```

Output:

```
(6, (1, 5))
(14, (1, 16))
(14, (2, 16))
(14, (3, 16))
(11, (0, 2))
```

#### First Iteration

Here is what I had originally, if you want to see the evolution of the thought processes. Here, I was essentially transliterating what I came up with on paper.

Essentially, we traverse the array and start flipping bits (ok, not really), keeping track of cumulative flipped zeros and cumulative flipped ones in two separate arrays along with the total flipped ones in an integer counter. If the difference between flipped ones and zeroes at a given index - the "net" - drops below zero, we 'reset' the cumulative counts back at zero at that index (but nothing else). Along the way, we also keep track of the maximum net we've achieved and the index at which that occurs. Thus, the total is simply the total 1's we've seen, plus the net at the maximum index.

```
arr = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
total_one = 0
one_flip =  [0 for _ in range(len(arr))]
zero_flip = [0 for _ in range(len(arr))]

# deal with first element of array
if arr[0]:
    total_one += 1
else:
    zero_flip[0] = 1

maximum = dict(index=0,value=0) #index, value
i = 1
# now deal with the rest
while i < len(arr):
    # if element is 1 we definitely increment total_one, else, we definitely flip
    if arr[i]:
        total_one += 1
        one_flip[i] = one_flip[i-1] + 1
        zero_flip[i] = zero_flip[i-1]
    else:
        zero_flip[i] = zero_flip[i-1] + 1
        one_flip[i] = one_flip[i-1]

    net = zero_flip[i] - one_flip[i]
    if net > 0:
        if maximum['value'] < net:
            maximum['value'] = net
            maximum['index'] = i
    else: # net == 0, we restart counting our "net"
        one_flip[i] = 0
        zero_flip[i] = 0

    i += 1

maximum_flipped = total_one - one_flip[maximum['index']] + zero_flip[maximum['index']]
```

Results:

```
print(total_one, -one_flip[maximum['index']], zero_flip[maximum['index']] )
print(maximum_flipped)
print('________________________________________________')
print(zero_flip, arr, one_flip, sep='\n')
print('maximum index', maximum['index'])
```

Output:

```
3 -1 4
6
________________________________________________
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
maximum index 5
```

if

`arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`

```
6 -4 12
14
________________________________________________
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
maximum index 16
```

Finally, if

`arr = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

```
8 0 3
11
________________________________________________
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
maximum index 2
```

### Great, now tear it apart, people!

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the whole array. Keep a `count` in the following way:

- Do `+1` for every 0 bit encountered.
- Do `-1` for every 1.

If this count reaches -ve at any stage, reset it to 0. Keep track of `max` value of this `count`. Add this `max_count` to number of `1's` in input array. This will be your answer.

**Code:**

```
arr = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
# I'm taking your sample case. Take the input the way you want

count,count_max,ones = 0,0,0

for i in arr:
    if i == 1:
        ones += 1
        count -= 1
    if i == 0:
        count += 1
    if count_max < count:
        count_max = count
    if count < 0:
        count = 0

print (ones + count_max)
```

Small and simple :)

Comment: Ah yes, this is much simpler. I don't recall why I kept track of the cumulative in separate lists. I could have sworn there was some reason why I felt it was necessary, but this is simpler. Small tidbit: increment `i` or else you have a infinite loop.

Comment: ... what's with that `while` loop? Just do `for el in arr: if el == 1: ...` if you need both the element and the index use `for index, element in enumerate(sequence)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu meh, this isn't really a Python question (even though it says as much in the title). While-loops are very translatable to any imperative language. Python has a particularly nice for-each construct, but this question is more about the meat of the solutions, rather than making it Pythonic. Just my two-cents.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then it should probably be asked on ComputerScience.SE instead of StackOverflow. I'd rather avoid having bad python code. If you want to give a pseudocode solution do so *in pseudocode* so that it is not confused with actual python code, and if you add a python implementation write one that is good, not ugly and unneccessary inefficient.

Comment: @Bakuriu I agree, this question should probably be on ComputerScience.SE.

Comment: @Bakuriu OK. I went ahead and wrote a more idiomatic version. You are right, we shouldn't encourage the use of while-loops when we are simply traversing a sequence in Python. That really is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Bakuriu, thanks for the insight. I'm also new to python myself...so made a mistaks which shud not have been made !!